# Nearest Neighbors algorithm with timestamp

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime, timestamp, nearest-neighbor

I have a .txt file with 3 dimensions. X,Y,time. My file looks something like this: "10 10 12:00" with many more points and times under it. I have found the Nearest points with just the X,Y values but now I need help finding the Nearest Neighbors with time involved.

For example, "what's the closest point to "10 10"? I have a point in my file that is "11 11", which is the closest point.

Now with time added:

What is the closest point to "10 10 12:00": is it "11 11 22:00" or is it "15 15 12:05". My format is "Xvalue, Yvalue, Time".

Comment: It's not clear how the distance should be calculated when a time is involved. The closest point to `10 10 12:00` is `11 11 22:00` or `15 15 12:05`? Or both are in the same distance from `10 10 12:00`? Can you please [edit] the question and clarify it?

Comment: If the correct answer is `15 15 12:05` because it is 5 minutes away from `10 10 12:00`, then can the X and Y coords just be ignored, and it becomes a simple time comparison?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Any NN algorithm depends strongly on the distance measure.

So you need to decide how you can calculate distances between points including times and that's part of the problem at hand. I would say that the best way would be to use ordinal distance between points but with introduction of a penalty using the difference in times.

But there is no 'single good answer' - you need to develop distance measure yourself based on specific problem you are trying to solve.